# Loading machine learning library without enabling my discrete Nvidia GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, librarylink

I've asked a similar question
 [[here]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189624/46453).

I cannot use some of the machine learning modules without enabling my discrete Nvidia GPU.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS-15 9560 Intel i7 CPU with 8-cores,
- Integrated IntelHD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) card
- Discrete Nvidia GTX-1050 card

To save power and reduce noise, I disable the discrete graphics card (using the Nvidia prime-select tool) . In this mode, running NetTrain leads to the error:

LibraryFunction::libload: The function WL_MXGetVersion was not loaded from the file /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/Components/MXNetLink/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/MXNetLink.so.

Re-enabling the Nvidia graphics card and rebooting fixes this problem. However, the default mode of NetTrain is to run with 'TargetDevice -> "CPU" ' so surely I should not need to enable my Nvidia card to get this to work.

[image]

Comment: I expect it would be more fruitful to speak to Wolfram Support about this since it seems like a bug in the underlying system.

Comment: @CarlLange - Hey, remember you from the last post! Yes, I've contacted Wolfram Supported and posted in Wolfram Community, still no response. Hoping that someone else has seen this, but as you said in the other post, it could be an edge case.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I hadn't realised I commented on the previous post as well!